# specify relative image path

Tags: c#, winforms

I have three class libraries in my project. In third class library I have a image. I was specifying path like D:\Desktop\popUp\wg.png. I want to specify general path like ~/Operators/wg.png. how to do that ?
project name is ChatApp and third class library is Operators!

Comment: You can include your image as a resource, that way it would always be "in place".

Comment: I pasted images in resources and try to do Properties.Resources.WG but its not showing WG. I compile and restart VS but could not find it.